# urllib.request.urlopen(url) not working in python 3

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib

The url i'm trying to hit is 'http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2554/2554.txt'

The code i'm using is

```
import urllib.request

url = 'http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2554/2554.txt'

f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
```

Error is :

```
HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

If I open the Url in browser, it works perfectly well.

What should i do to get the ebook present at the url to be read as str. I'm using Python 3.5

Comment: My browser gives me a 404. Perhaps you need to first login? If so you need a solution that can persist a session across multiple requests.

Comment: Weird. The url opened correctly the first time I clicked it, but now it's giving me a 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is because that url doesn't exist even if you try manually it will not open that url

**try this**

```
url = http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2554/2554-0.txt
```